# strings not showing in console

Tags: printing, console

For some reason this isn't showing what I write in the console - It's not printing in the console. I may be getting confused with the static thing. Also, how come the getUserInformation() method is a void when it is returning information from the console to the variables declared? Thanks

```
    namespace Student_Information
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string firstName = string.Empty, lastName = string.Empty, birthday = string.Empty;
            getUserInformation();
            printStudentDetails(firstName, lastName, birthday);
        }

        static void getUserInformation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's first name: ");
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's last name");
            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your bithdate");
            string birthday = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void printStudentDetails(string firstName, string lastName, string birthday)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} was born on: {2}", firstName, lastName, birthday);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Console.WriteLine(firstName+" "+lastName+" was born on: "+birthday);
```

Comment: Nope" still getting the same. Just reads "Blank Blank was born on: blank"